# Redirect to google pay on click

Tags: html, redirect, payment, google-pay, upi

Currently I'm working on web project in which I need a feature such that :

1. There is a button
2. Clicking on the button will redirect the user to the google pay mobile application in tha mobile phone
3. (Optional) which will auto fill the upi id of the person to which the money is to be transfered.

how can I accomplish this feature

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="upi://pay?pa=UPIID@oksbi&amp;pn=FNAME SNAME K&amp;cu=INR"
>Pay Now !</a>
```

**Refer this link:**
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852954/how-to-invoke-upi-payment-apps-from-url)